# Qt application migrated from windows 7 to windows 10, but some warnings

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have written an application in Qt 5.4 (windows 7 ) and now migrating it to windows 10 Qt 5.5.. there are some changes in qt i already correct it in code and code builds well, but when it comes to run program there are a bunch of warnings . I dont know where and why it comes from.

Warnings :

```
shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(9456)\comdlg32.dll!00007FFF0973260A: (caller: 00007FFF0973A866) ReturnHr[PreRelease](1) tid(b94) 80070490 Element not found.
    CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop\InitDialog\FileDialogInitEnterpriseData] 
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFEE54432DC: (caller: 00007FFEE54434FF) ReturnHr[PreRelease](1) tid(b94) 80004005 Unspecified error
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFEE5438D28: (caller: 00007FFF06713EA0) ReturnHr[PreRelease](2) tid(b94) 80004005 Unspecified error
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFEE54432DC: (caller: 00007FFEE54434FF) ReturnHr[PreRelease](3) tid(b94) 80004005 Unspecified error
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!00007FFEE54432DC: (caller: 00007FFEE54434FF) ReturnHr[PreRelease](4) tid(b94) 80004005
```

Comment: This warnings have nothing to do with QT. Same with an old MFC project with VisualStudio 2010 under Win10 ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue was discussed [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56599) by the Qt guys, and they say they cannot do anything about it:

> This is unrelated to Qt; the same happens when opening a file in notepad.
>   Picker is RT terminology; it seems the dialog is implemented in terms of a WinRT file picker and something goes awry there.